# English translation of G.Laumon, L.Moret-Bailly book Champs algébriques

Tags: reference-request, stacks, algebraic-stacks, translation

Is there an English translation of G.Laumon, L.Moret-Bailly book Champs algébriques.

Most questions on this site on stacks received this book as reference in comments/answers.

So, I want to ask if there is an English translation for this. Or, are there any seminar pages (in English) where material in that book is discussed?

Edit : Has anything changed in last 15 months? Any information regarding possible translation of the book?

Comment: You can be quite certain that there is none, because it is Springer copyrighted and they have not translated it: On their web site it says "A 'must' for every library and for all algebraic geometers, even if their knowledge of French is only basic".

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Seminars based on that book option is still there :)

Comment: If you want something in English, consider the Stacks project.

Comment: I can not search for a result in stacks project. Suppose some one refer proposition 4.26 in that book, how do I search for that in stacks project. :O @S.Carnahan

Comment: You feed the French into your favorite translation website, and look for a similar result in the Stacks project (or some other reference on stacks).

Comment: @S.Carnahan That seems to be the only option if I could not find any thing useful. I did not think of your suggestion before. Thanks.

Comment: The book has been out for a long time. There is no incentive to translate it, for the publisher. I don't envisage the situation changing.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I feel the same.. Are you aware of any seminar pages that use this book.. It is slightly frustrating when some one says some book is too good and I don't get to read it or know what is there in it...

Comment: Not that I know of. I would just search online for it, and don't have any special tricks that I can tell you of.